# Почему ESLint указывает на ошибку в import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, зависимости

Данную ошибку:

"*'**webpack-stream**' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies.eslintimport/no-extraneous-dependencies*"

(где **webpack-stream** - любой модуль)

в коде:

```
import webpack from 'webpack-stream';
```

(т.е. ругает на то, что зависимости прописаны в devDependencies, а не в dependencies.)

Вопросы:

- Почему он рекомендует указывать зависимости именно в **dependencies**
  (*какие зависимости стоит указывать в **dependecies** и какие в **devDependencies***)
- Как настроить ESLint так, чтобы он принимал мои настройки зависимостей как **правильные**

Comment: Наверное, потому что зависимости, прописанные в `devDependencies` недоступны во время выполнения.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Доступны

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Comment: признаю, что не заметил, что именно за зависимость была...линтовщик там и должен быть.

Comment: тогда вам стоит посмотреть это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939304/eslint-should-be-listed-in-the-projects-dependencies-not-devdependencies

Comment: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md#options